# Download gitlab release source in CI build?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there a way to download the source associated with a particular release in gitlab from a CI job?

If I interrogate the asset list using the API, I am able to see the source assets, but how can they be downloaded? The paths return from those requests require manual login, which I don't think I can do in an automated CI build.

I cannot use the repository API because that does not accept CI tokens, only personal ones.

Comment: If it works for you, you can probably just use `git clone` using the ref associated with the release.